# Date.js getWeek() stopped working after implementing Extjs

Tags: javascript, date, extjs

I had an existing site that was using the date.js library and it stopped working after I implemented a Extjs Border Layout ( http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html ) into my site.

So the line in question is this one:

```
var weeknum = (dates[y][m][d]).getWeek();
```

Firebug tells me that dates[y][m][d].getWeek is not a function.

Now from my understanding, Extjs extends the javascript date object which is the probable cause for this issue. I tried changing the line of code above to use the Extjs getWeekOfYear() but I still get the same error.

Any ideas on how I can keep my existing getWeek() code and still be able to use Extjs?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Did a

```
console.log((dates[y][m][d]));
```

[image: Firefox Console]

Edit2:
[image: Showing Ext.isDate, not a function, and function?]

Comment: What does dates[y][m][d] get you?

Comment: A Date Object. It was working fine with date.js

Comment: Can you confirm that it is a `Date` by doing: `Ext.isDate(dates[y][m][d])`? My suspicion is that that is not a `Date`, and the problem is not specifically to do with Ext.

Comment: (dates[y][m][d]) is a date object I'll update with a screen shot of an older working version. I wasn't able to try the Ext.isDate method you suggested. But I will in a few

Comment: Just tried out the Ext.isDate and it's reporting true. Hmm..

Comment: It's the not-working version that I think isn't a Date object any more, though.

Comment: Ah. Try this in the console: `new Date().getWeek`

Comment: Check out the screen shot in Edit2. I'm confused after entering that line in the console, does the return of function() prove that it is a function?

Comment: Yes. The `Date` prototype has the function as expected. That part is working. What's not working is the values in `dates[y][m][d]`. You can see that instead of a `Date` they're `true` -- so no `getWeek` function.

Comment: Sorry I updated the code to try `console.log(Ext.isDate(dates[y][m][d]));` Which is why you are see true being listed several times instead of the dates.

Comment: Reaching here -- does `dates[y][m][d].__proto__ === Date.prototype`?

Comment: Put that line inside the console.log and I got true returned again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing all my references to the Date.js file on any page that was going to us Ext. It wasn't as complicated as I thought it would be. Not ideal, but at least it's working now.